# Sharepoint Online Provider Hosted App on Azure, HTTP 500 during the provisioning

Tags: provider-hosted-app

I have an MVC site hosted on Azure and a SharePoint App on Office 365.

This Office App open the MVC Site that provide a button to make the provisioning.

When I start the provisioning the Mvc Controller is called and the provisioning is working and I see that the browser is waiting for the response.

After a lot of time the browser return a 500 error without message but the provisioning is still working because I have put a breakpoint on the final code of the controller.

So it seems that the provisioning went wrong, but it is still working.

I try to put this  on the MVC controller

```
HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = 900;
```

without any success.

How can I manage with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I had, probably, the same issue. The Application consists with two projects. SharePoint Project and MVC. The MVC app was deployed to Azure as website. The app was working fine, and the suddenly it stopped some day and the HTTP 500 error was returned.

After investigation it was discovered that app was deployed a one year ago. By reading logs files and analyzing request/response it seemed the problem with Security token or with trust between Auzre part and SharePoint.

And the I found this article.

http://www.sharepoint-reference.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=47

I hope it will help.